# Bootstrap multiple collapsible panels error

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Hello i wanted to implement a collapsible pannels into my website if you are not sure what do i talk about i use this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Panel 1</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">text here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Panel 2</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">text here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

now the problem is that , whenever i try to add more of them and lets say i have like 3 of these codes on my site then whenever i click at any of these pannels header it only opens the first i understand whats wrong with it , its because it triggers a div when you click the panel header and if the div ids are the same in every of these group then clicking on it will apply the change to the first group so then i renamed

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Panel 1</a>
```

to

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1B">Panel 1</a>
```

and also

to

```
  <div id="collapse1B" class="panel-collapse collapse">
```

and now whenever i click at any of them the changes will only aply to the one it should but , as you can see if you click at panel option 1 the option 2 will slide back , and this feature doesnot work anymore if i do what i described above can anyone tell me how to use multiple collapsible group on my site without loosing the feature to slide back when you choose the second option ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just delete `id="accordion"` and `data-parent="accordion"`:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Panel 1</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">text here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2">Panel 2</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">text here</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm your question is not clear. Maybe just use different IDs for all panels and different href attributes? Because you can not have more than 1 element of the same ID on one HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

The `data-parent` [attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_collapse.asp) specifies a collection of elements to collapse when triggered.  I think of it like a Radio Group: only one can be selected.

As @makshh said, if you remove that it will work.  You only need to use that attribute if you wish to have multiple collapsibles linked.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Panel 1</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">text here</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2">Panel 2</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">text here</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```